# Rights of funding data in research

Tags: publications

I have used data of my colleague with her permission in my article while that data was funded by an external organization for her other project. Although my research is not funded by that organization, I made use of some data.

Is it okay to acknowledge my colleague and the other organization in my article, or do I have to provide funding details to answer the question '*Did the research in this article receive funding?*'.

Thanks

Comment: You may need to know the acknowledgement policies of the organisation which funded the data collection. I work for a funder, and while we support data sharing and reuse we also insist on an acknowledgement of our funding using some specific phrasing.

Answer (score 5):

I would write:

*The research in this article did not receive third party funding. The research is (partially) based on data gathered within the project xyz which was funded by abc. We would like to thank uvw for the data acquisition and support.*